# TypeError: dynamoDb.deleteTable is not a function

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Getting this error "TypeError: dynamoDb.deleteTable is not a function"

```
const { dynamoDb, DEVICES_TABLE } = require('./startup/db')

var params = {
    TableName: DEVICES_TABLE
};

dynamoDb.deleteTable(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to delete table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Deleted table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: This error is saying `deleteTable` is not a function on your `dynamoDb` object.  How are you defining that object?  What is in './startup/db'?

Comment: Its a lambda code with dynamoDB as `dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment in your question, you are calling `deleteTable` on `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`.  However, the `deleteTable` method is defined on `AWS.DynamoDB`, which is a different class (confusing, I know).

Here's what it should look like

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
 // your config options here ....
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName : "YOUR_TABLE_NAME"
};

dynamodb.deleteTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to delete table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Deleted table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: omg, thanks. I thought I break my code and it's not working because of that...